# Clipped element not updating on clip-path changes

Tags: css, svg

I got an image created in js with a clip-path css attribute.
I'm also creating an svg with a clip-path in svg, with a circle used as mask.
Rendered it looks like this :

```
`<svg id="ayads-bubble-svg" height="0" width="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="bubble-path">
      <circle cx="188" cy="117" r="229">
      </circle>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>`
```

I'm changing circle r attribute on scroll, but my image clip isn't updated (while if I disable and enable clip-path in inspector it works).

I'll be really please if you guys have an idea
Thanks a lot !

Comment: How are you changing the r attribute?

Comment: Both tried setAttribute and setAttributeNS


`$circle.setAttribute('r', 30);
$circle.setAttributeNS(null,'r', 30);`

Comment: Please include a working example of your code.  Also, is it failing in all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say where your *leprechaun* sits, if we don't have all (related) pieces of code. However, I made an simple example which works just fine, for me (chrome v51.0+).

I hope this helps.

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('circle')

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var delta = window.scrollY / (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight)
  circle.setAttribute('r', 50 - delta * 25)
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 200%;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="bubble-path">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100" height="100" clip-path="url(#bubble-path)" />
</svg>

Scroll Down
```